# Fast custom Photo Viewer for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I created a custom PhotoViewer for my WP8 App but it works quite slow (1-3 sec. loading per image), at least not as good as a standard Photo Viewer in WP.
I use FlipView where each FlipViewItem has an Image control. **In order to save memory and not get OutOfMemoryError, every time user changes a selected FlipViewItem I load a photo Stream from MediaLibrary, compress it using DecodePixelWidth and display it in the Image control of the selected FW item and I dispose the previous Image stream**. So **it's a quite heavy** operations but anyway I cannot load all Streams from around 100 photos at the same time.

**Can anybody advice me a better way to build the PhotoViewer with performance close to standard Windows Phone Photo Viewer or like in Nokia Storyteller App?**
Or maybe somebody knows some open-source controls or app with this functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I am begging the obvious question, but couldn't you just pre-load next/previous images instead of the entire library?

Comment: I do so, but anyway, if I pre-load previous+current+next images it takes time (e.g. 3 sec) and when apply BitmapImage as a Source of Image control with downsampling using DecodePixelWidth also takes time so when I open my PhotoViewer page I wait 3-4 sec until it completely opens and loads those 3 images.

Comment: I am doing similar things, you may try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547103/how-to-improve-performance-method-getthumbnailasync-in-window-phone-8-1