# How to improve performance method GetThumbnailAsync in window phone 8.1

Tags: c#, image-processing, optimization, winrt-xaml

I write a function to show images on a folder (assume i have about **60 images** in this folder) in window phone 8.1. And the problem  is **function GetThumbnailAsync() take so long time** when i create stream to get bitmapImage.
Here's my code

```
       //getFileInPicture is function get all file in picture folder 
       List<StorageFile> lstPicture = await getFileInPicture();
       foreach (var file in lstPicture)
       {
            var thumbnail = await        file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,50);
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)(ScreenWidth / 4);
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(thumbnail);
            g_listBitmapImage.Add(bitmapImage);
           //g_listBitmapImage is a list of bitmapImage
        }
```

I was test and **find the problem is function GetThumbnailAsync take so long time**.
If i have about 60 picture it take about 15second to finish this function( i test in lumia 730).
***Have anybody get this problem and how to make this code run faster ?***.

Thanks so much for your supports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently awaiting `file.GetThumbnailAsync` for each file which means that although the function is executed asynchronously for each file, it is executed in order, not in parallel.

Try converting each async operation returned from `file.GetThumbnailAsync`to a `Task` and then storing those in a list and then `await` all tasks using `Task.WhenAll`.

```
List<StorageFile> lstPicture = await getFileInPicture();
List<Task<StorageItemThumbnail>> thumbnailOperations =  List<Task<StorageItemThumbnail>>();

   foreach (var file in lstPicture)
   {
        thumbnailOperations.Add(file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,50).AsTask());
   }

   // wait for all operations in parallel
   await Task.WhenAll(thumbnailOperations);

   foreach (var task in thumbnailOperations)
   {
       var thumbnail = task.Result;
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)(ScreenWidth / 4);
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(thumbnail);
        g_listBitmapImage.Add(bitmapImage);
       //g_listBitmapImage is a list of bitmapImage
   }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your help, but this function thumbnailOperations.Add(file.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.PicturesView,50)) has a error. file.getThumbnailAsync() has a IAsyncOperation<StorageItemThumbnail> type, and make thumbnailOperations can't add it.

Comment: @PhamLuc It looks like the answerer made a typo: put `.StartAsTask()` in the inner part of the parentheses, right after `.GetThumbnailAsync()`.

Comment: @James Ko , sorry but file.GetThumbnailAsync() doen't have function .StartAsTask(), so can't put as what you say..

Comment: @PhamLuc Try deleting `.StartAsTask()`, putting a dot next to it, and seeing if there's any method in the autocompletion that indicates it can convert it to `Task` (i.e. `.AsTask()`). If that doesn't work, try and see if you can add a using statement to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, because there's an extension method to convert `IAsyncOperation` to `Task` there.

Comment: @James Ko, thanks so much. After add .AsTask(), the code can run on debug mode of visual studio 2013. It get faster than about 5second. But if i run without visual studio 2013, it crash. could you add my skype nick ? or give me your email, i will send my code for your review. my skype mail : thichchoi_honhoc@yahoo.com

Comment: I have fixed the typo, what error do you get when the code crashes?

Comment: @NedStoyanov : You Sir have saved the day.Thank you so much!